# How to prevent specific Yocto recipes from being installed into eSDK?

Tags: sdk, cross-compiling, yocto, bitbake, recipe

Is there a way to prevent specific Yocto recipes (the recipe's headers, libs, etc.) from being installed into the eSDK?

I am fairly new to Yocto and am trying to build an eSDK of `SDK_EXT_TYPE = "full"`, to allow for cross compiling for qemux86-64 with vanilla CMake tools. My image has some custom recipes and some third-party recipes. **I only want to exclude the custom recipes, but include the dependencies of the custom recipes.**

The workflow that I am trying to achieve is to be able to use "devtool-modify" on these custom recipes and then cross-compile them from within my workspace. The additional of the SDK_EXT_TYPE = "full" allows me to set my gcc --sysroot to the eSDK's sysroot, which provides me with all the third-party header files/libraries that my custom recipes need to cross-compile from my workspace.

The only issue with this is that the **eSDK's sysroot directory also includes header files/libraries that are part of my custom recipes**, and those header files/libraries also exist in my workspace (after I used devtool-modify). This causes duplicate header files, since for example, my_header.h exists in:

```
tmp/sysroots/usr/include/ (eSDK sysroot) and 
workspace/sources/<recipe_name>/include/
```

Most of the time the eSDK sysroot my_header.h is included instead of the workspace my_header.h, which causes compilation errors if I modified my_header.h in my workspace.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I tried adding the following to local.conf (separately) but the custom recipe's header files/libraries still kept on showing up under sysroot when I extract the eSDK:

```
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_remove = "my_recipe"

EXCLUDE_FROM_WORLD_pn-my_recipe = "1"

TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_remove = "my_recipe"
```

My image recipe contains the line:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "my_recipe"
```

Here is what my custom recipe looks like:

```
# my-recipe.bb

LICENSE = "CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = ""

SRC_URI = "<recipe-src-url>"

SRCREV = "${BUILDCFG_GITTAG}"
PV = "1.0+git${SRCPV}"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

DEPENDS += "my-other-recipe"

inherit pkgconfig cmake

EXTRA_OECMAKE = " -DYOCTO_CMAKE=1"
```

Thanks in advance!